# Extract cell with AND without commas in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the city and state from the Address column into 2 separate columns labeled City and State in r. This is what my data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(address = c("Los Angeles, CA", "Pittsburgh PA", "Miami FL","Baltimore MD", "Philadelphia, PA", "Trenton, NJ")) %>%

separate(address, c("City", "State"), sep=",")
```

I tried using the separate function but that only gets the ones with commas. Any ideas on how to do this for both cases?
There is a pattern at the end (space, letter, letter) which I can use to exploit and then remove any commas but not sure how the syntax would work using grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your df

```
df <- data.frame(address = c("Los Angeles, CA", "Pittsburgh PA", "Miami FL","Baltimore MD", "Philadelphia, PA", "Trenton, NJ"))
> df
           address
1  Los Angeles, CA
2    Pittsburgh PA
3         Miami FL
4     Baltimore MD
5 Philadelphia, PA
6      Trenton, NJ
```

It's possible to use gsub to subset the string like this:

```
> city=gsub(',','',gsub("(.*).{3}","\\1",df[,1]))
> city
[1] "Los Angeles"  "Pittsburgh"   "Miami"        "Baltimore"    "Philadelphia"
[6] "Trenton"     
> state=gsub(".*(\\w{2})","\\1",df[,1])
> state
[1] "CA" "PA" "FL" "MD" "PA" "NJ"

df=data.frame(City=city,State=state)
> df
          City State
1  Los Angeles    CA
2   Pittsburgh    PA
3        Miami    FL
4    Baltimore    MD
5 Philadelphia    PA
6      Trenton    NJ
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unorthodox but it works well. It assumes that all states are 2 characters long and that there is at least 1 space between the city and state. Comma's are ignored

```
df <- data.frame(address = c("Los Angeles, CA", "Pittsburgh PA", "Miami FL","Baltimore MD", "Philadelphia, PA", "Trenton, NJ")) 

df$city <- substring(sub(",","",df$address),1,nchar(sub(",","",df$address))-3)
df$state <- substring(as.character(df$address),nchar(as.character(df$address))-1,nchar(as.character(df$address)))

df <- within(df,rm(address))
```

output:

```
          city state
1  Los Angeles    CA
2   Pittsburgh    PA
3        Miami    FL
4    Baltimore    MD
5 Philadelphia    PA
6      Trenton    NJ
```